# jQuery POST not passing POST variables?

Tags: php, jquery

I've got a form that uses a jQuery POST function to pass variables to a PHP file with a switch function.  One of the variables POSTed is called "indicator"... this variable is evaluated by the switch, and depending on its value, a differ case will execute.

I've verified that everything on the front end works, but for some reason I cannot get any output from the PHP file. The switch stack in the PHP file may be working correctly, but I'm just not seeing any output on the front end.  tried doing a simple variable dump from the back end, and still nada.  Any thoughts?  Thank you all

I've included the code to my form, jQuery function called when submitting the form, and the backend PHP switch:

```
FORM:

<form id="createAcc" onsubmit="return createAccResults();" style="height: 800px; top: 53%;">
            <input type="submit" id="createAccSubmit" name="createAccSubmit" value="Submit"></br>
            <h3 id="usernameTxt">Create username</h3>
            <p id="instructions">(Any length & combo of letters and numbers)</p>
            <input id="userName" name="userName" type="text" value=""></br>
            <h3 id="emailTxt">Enter email address.</h3>
            <input id="email" name="email" type="text" value=""></br>
            <h3 id="pwTxt">Create password</h3>
            <p id="instructions">(Must be min. 6 char long & contain at least 1 number, 1 lowercase & 1 uppercase letter)</p>
            <input id="password" name="password" type="password" value=""></br>
            <h3 id="pwConfTxt">Confirm password</h3>
            <input id="passwordConf" name="passwordConf" type="password" value="">
            <h3 id="secQuestion1" style="font-family: cursive; font-style: italic; color: white;">Security Question 1:</h3>
            <p id="question1" style="font-family: cursive; font-style: italic; color: white;">What is your childhood nickname?</p>
            <input id="sQ1" name="sQ1" type="text" value="" style="width: 350px; height: 30px; border-radius: 20px;"></br>
            <h3 id="secQuestion2" style="font-family: cursive; font-style: italic; color: white;">Security Question 2:</h3>
            <p id="question2" style="font-family: cursive; font-style: italic; color: white;">Where were you born?</p>
            <input id="sQ2" name="sQ2" type="text" value="" style="width: 350px; height: 30px; border-radius: 20px;"></br>
        </form>



JQUERY POST:

function createAccResults() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var pw = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var indicator = 2;
    var eml = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var inpU = document.getElementById("userName").value;
    var inpPC = document.getElementById("passwordConf").value;
    conditionss = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}/,
    conditions = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/,
    conditionU = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
    if(!(conditionss.test(pw)) || !(conditions.test(eml)) || !(conditionU.test(inpU)) || !(pw==inpPC)) {
        document.getElementById('userName').value = "";
        document.getElementById('email').value = "";
        document.getElementById('password').value = "";
        document.getElementById('passwordConf').value = "";
        alert("Please complete form correctly");
    } else {
        $("#createAcc").css("display","none");
        $("#revealAcc").css("display","none");
        $("#uploadTrg").show();
        $.post("updateProfile.php", {un: inpU, pw: pw, eml: eml, indicator: indicator},
                    function(returned) {
                        document.getElementById("uploadTrg").innerHTML = returned;
                    });
            };
    });
    return false;
};



PHP SWITCH:

$UsrN = $_POST['un'];
$eml = $_POST['eml'];;
$pswrd = $_POST['pw'];
$usernameMatch = preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $UserN);
$emailMatch = preg_match('/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/', $eml);
$pwMatch = preg_match('/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}/', $pswrd);
$query = "SELECT email FROM accounts WHERE username='$UserN' OR email='$eml' OR password='$pswrd'";
$results = $pdo->query($query);
$indicator = $_POST['indicator'];

switch($indicator) {
        case 2:
            if($results == 0 && $pwMatch == 1 && $emailMatch == 1 && $usernameMatch == 1) {
            $query4 = "INSERT INTO accounts (username, email, password, about) VALUES ('$userN', '$eml', '$pswrd', 'Add a little about yourself')";
            $results4 = $pdo->query($query4);
            $message = "Account created successfully! Please login";
            } else if ($usernameMatch === false || $emailMatch === false || $pwMatch === false) {
            $message = "Please complete form correctly";
            } else {
                $message = "Account info already taken";
            }
            echo "<p style='color: white; font-family: cursive; font-size: 35px; text-align: center;'>";
            echo $message;
            echo "</p>";
            break;
        case 3:
            SOME CODE THAT'S IRRELEVANT; PERTAINS TO ANOTHER JQUERY POST FUNCTION THAT WORKS FINE
        case 5:
            SOME CODE THAT'S IRRELEVANT; PERTAINS TO ANOTHER JQUERY POST FUNCTION THAT WORKS FINE
    }
```

Comment: Can you possibly provide your PHP, HTML and Javascript? Hard to help when we don't know what the code looks like.

Comment: Side note, your method is being called from the invocation of an inline event handler.  As such, the document ready inside the method is unnecessary.  The DOM has to have loaded by then.

Comment: man you guys got to it quick, before I could finish editing the post.  Accidentally submitted the question before adding all needed info.  Anyways, thank you for your quick response. Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the quick glance, your $.post looks syntatically correct.  So I'll ask again.  Did you verify the request in your network console to verify that the ajax request is sending all the correct parameters?

Comment: I have not tested that the variables are being passed correctly from the front end; I'll do this shortly.  Also, Taplar, understood and thank you

Comment: Another point of concern would be related to the switch statement.  It's been a while since I've done PHP, but my assumption would be that the `$indicator` would be a string value, not an integer, since it came from the request.  So if PHP doesn't treat string variables nicely with your cases being numerical values, 2 != "2" in PHP possibly.

Comment: So I just verified that the backend is getting all of the form POSTed data just fine, all is well there.

Comment: You are right Taplar, in that by default the $indicator variable is a string. However, the switch only compares value, not type.  Only on rare occasions will this cause issues, I'm totally aware of this, thank you.  btw, all of my other jQuery posts are working perfect, and they are sending a string value for $indicator, so the fact that it is a string type isn't posing any issue with my switch functionality  (loose comparison is what it's called, according to the PHP manual)

Comment: You've got a variable name wrong in the PHP code. You define `$UsrN`, but use `$UserN` in the SQL string. However, this wouldn't explain the absence of output, since you have (wrongly, I think) use `OR` instead of `AND` in the SQL.

Comment: Incidentally, do you realise it's dangerous to build SQL strings like this? (A malicious client could send data containing `'` characters, thus running SQL comments you didn't want them to run.)